# JQuery Context Menu on Selected Text

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a sample code for custom JQuerycontext menus appearing when some text is selected. 
There is a similar application on Quora, where an "Embed Text" div appears when a text is selected. (Could not get a sample through its listener though!)
And how can I get/change the selected text or wrap it in custom tags?

I have browsed a number of context menu plugins and yet could not combine text select event with a custom context menu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Couldn't you provide a jsfiddle?!

Comment: Thanks for your interest! Stackoverflow wouldn't let me post a picture of it so I uploaded it to: [link](http://imgur.com/pwS4F5j)
I just could not get started with the code, please do not perceive it as laziness, I am just a noob with Jquery :)

Comment: You should search for "tooltip" instead of "contextual menu" if I interpret your image correctly ;)